# Is there a C# or .NET class to handle HTTP Content Negotiation?

Tags: c#, http, content-negotiation

Is there a C# or .NET class to handle HTTP Content Negotiation with a User Agent?

I would like to be able to supply a list of acceptable Content Types, and have those negotiated with the browser to find the best match.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation
Content Negotiation is part of the HTTP Specification that allows a User Agent (browser) to list the media types it will accept a document in order of "quality". So in my code I would like to pass in the formats I can generate, and have the class apply the Content Negotiation rules as defined in the Specification and return me the best media type to send back.

Comment: If my application can render a piece of data in either HTML, XHTML, XML, PDF or JSON. I need to know which the browser supports, and specifically which one it considers the best quality.

Answer (score 1):

[I recently wrote a content negotiation library in F#](https://github.com/mausch/FsConneg).

I blogged about it [here](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2011/06/http-content-negotiation-library-in-f.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the word user agent is a bit off in your question but if you want to build request a certain source (lets say a restfull api). You can use the WCF Rest Starter kit (http://wcf.codeplex.com/) to specify the type of content you want or accept:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new Uri("http://restfull/api/"));
//this is XML but could be JSON or whatever the API can supply
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
var response = client.Get(path);

if (response != null)
{
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  //this will be XML
  string xml = response.Content.ReadAsString();
}
```

Comment: This is client-side code, the OP is asking about server-side code. Also, content negotiation in WCF is currently broken: http://wcf.codeplex.com/workitem/40